# AnglarJSでCookieの保存が遅延する。

Tags: php, angularjs, cookie

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
このサイトを参考にしてCSRF対策をしたのですが、以下のコードで自動的にHeaderとして送られるX-XSRF-TOKENが以前のものになってしまいます。

```js
$cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = data['token'];  //ここでサーバから送られたトークンをクッキーに保存している。ここで保存されるクッキーをcooke1とする
$scope.queries = Admin.query();            //このリクエストでサーバサイドでトークンの検証が行われるがX-XSRF-TOKENヘッダとして送られるトークンがcookie1ではなくcookie0なので、検証に失敗する。
//このあとcookie1が保存される?
//なおcookie0は以前のセッションでクッキーに登録されたトークン。
```

要するにリクエストのタイミングでまだクッキーが保存されていないのではないかとうのが私の予想です。なのでCookieの保存が終了時にリクエストを送ればいいのだと考えられますが、そのようなことはできるのでしょうか。もしできないのであれば別の方法を教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。
サーバサイドはPHPです。

こちらのサイトも参考にさせて頂きました。
http://blog.sarabande.jp/post/88301895178

Comment: 「Cookieの保存が遅延する」よりも「CSRF対策のトークン保管が遅延する？」の方がご質問の内容により近くなると思います。

残念ながらAngularJSはそこまで詳しくないので明確な答えはできないのですが、Cookieの保存はサーバからのレスポンスが終わって、ブラウザが描画完了したときに一緒に保管しますので、保管する命令を書いたとしてもそれはまだブラウザに保管されていないと予想します。

Comment: 私もそのように考えています。
GETでパラメータとして送信するようにしました。